# QPixmap does not open some image

Tags: c++, qt, null, qpixmap

It opens one JPEG image but not the other JPEG. The directories and files exist on my system. For ease of recreation the images used in the below code are [console test](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v1gsc7ckwibieel/console%20test.jpg?dl=0) and [f2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ekgo6nxt1937v1i/f2.jpg?dl=0).

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    QPixmap *pixmap = new QPixmap;

    pixmap->load("C:/Programs/console test.jpg");
    if(pixmap->isNull())
        cout << "darn" << endl;
    else
        cout << "not null" << endl;

    pixmap->load("C:/Programs/f2.jpg");

    if(pixmap->isNull())
        cout << "darn" << endl;
    else
        cout << "not null" << endl;

    return a.exec();
}
```

The above code prints

```
darn
not null
```

If relevant, the application is a QWidget application.

Comment: I know that's a stupid thing to say in 2015, but what happens if you remove the space in the name of the first one ?

Comment: I replaced the space with an underscore and it still persisted. It has to do with the file itself (I infer) and not to do with the file name. If it means anything, ifstream opens and writes the file without problems.

Comment: Have you tried forcing it to load using a particular format using the optional parameter?

Comment: `console test.jpg` is actually a PNG file.

Comment: @Oktalist you are correct! That being said, is there anyway to convert between png and jpg in c++ using Standard C++ Libraries or Qt Libraries?

Comment: @Oktalist Just curious, how did you know `console test.jpg` is a actually PNG file when it has `.jpg` extension?

Comment: @Tay2510 According to spec. the first eight bytes of a PNG datastream always contain the following (decimal) values: 137 80 78 71 13 10 26 10. Here 80 78 71 are ASCII codes for 'P', 'N', 'G'.

Comment: [`file` command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_%28command%29).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> console test.jpg is actually a PNG file. –  Oktalist

Oktalist answered the question. I naively used  and changed the extension from png to jpg expecting file conversion. After undoing the change with the same method, the image successfully opens.

```
ifstream src("console print.jpg", ios::binary);
ofstream dest("console print.png", ios::binary);
dest << src.rdbuf();
dest.flush();
```

And now console print has the correct file extension. And it opens. There are a billion other ways you could do this, but this one was easy.

-Sanfer

Comment: This does not answer the question. Only complete solutions to the problem should be posted as answers. If you have additional information, please post a comment or update your question.